# Using innerHTML to include HTML Django page not work

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to include an HTML when a button is clicked in a Django project but the error a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Here is the Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("workout_table").innerHTML = '{% include 'app/log_form.html' %}';
```

The error showing is at this line of code as if the include code is not there at all.
[image]

My question:
How can I add this code through javascript and avoid this error

Comment: Is this javascript code within the html template file or in a separate javascript file?

Comment: The unexpected token would appear to be in the content of  `{% include 'app/log_form.html' %}` inserted by the server into the page template. You could create link to the web page on the front end, right click the link and save to disk to verify what is actually being sent. Note that as coded in the post, _the content would need to comply with the syntax for the content of a single quoted string value in JavaScript._

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr it is within the html file not a separate file

Comment: Try changing quotation marks to Grave accent.

Comment: @itsmehemant7 this worked perfectly fine if you would add it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @A_K it is a very common problem. I have added an answer ...upvote(s) will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing quotation marks to Grave accent :

```
document.getElementById("workout_table").innerHTML = `{% include 'app/log_form.html' %}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
document.getElementById("workout_table").innerHTML = {% json.dumps( include 'app/log_form.html') %};
```

Note the absence of quote marks around `{% ... %}`, which is based on the assumption that Python's `json.dumps` method returns  a string of characters starting and ending with ASCII double quote marks in the same way as  `JSON.stringify` does in JavaScript.

If the syntax of `{% json.dumps( include 'app/log_form.html) %}` is incorrect, please amend it to cause the string content of file `app.log_form.html` to be serialized as a JSON string and included in generated HTML.